# Is it possible to add a custom view to an existing MVC site where you do not have access to the project files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to add a custom view to an existing MVC site where you do not have access to the project files?

I have a third party MVC website installed on my server. The site has a built in mechanism for accessing outside webpages by loading them into an iFrame.

Is there a way to add a custom .cshtml page to the same directory as the third party MVC site and have it recognized by the site without editing the dlls?

Comment: Something in that MVC application would need to know to look for your custom razor page.  Unless you deleted an existing page and replaced it with yours with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because MVC.net finds views by convention. You could in theory place a correctly named view in the correct location and it would run instead of the other view. I'm not sure what this would accomplish though.

You could certainly copy and change an existing view. Perhaps if you edited the default view of the site you could register specific routes or load an additional dll with controllers from within the default view.

I've never tried this though, so certain code may not run inside a view. I certainly would have disallowed precisely this sort of code from running from within a view if I were designing mvc.net.

I hope my musings help.